# parse xml using java for recursive xpath node

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have xml with a repeating node structure within single node. How do I parse all the values by level?

```
<Totallevel>3</Totallevel>
<A>
  <B>text</B>
  <level>1</level>
  <A>
    <B>text</B>
    <level>2</level>
    <A>
      <B>text</B>
      <level>3</level>
    </A>
  </A>
</A>
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? Please provide an example

Answer (score 0):

That would allow you to specify level

```
//A[level='2']
```

If you need to get value from B than example is here for level 2

```
//A[level='2']/B
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your xml with `DocumentBuilder` so that you can get the `Document`. 
Iterates then using `getChildNodes()` method from the root down to leaf